# Show diffrent data in UITableView with two UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UITableView` that has one `UICollectionView` and
I used `numberOfRowsInSection` to set the number of rows and `cellForRowAt` to show cells with title:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return sectionsArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let strname = sectionsArray[indexPath.row]
    if (strname as AnyObject).isEqual(to: "top"){
        tableCellobj = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellmiddle", for: indexPath) as! TableCellMiddle

        tableCellobj.lblMiddle.text = "\(strname)"
        return tableCellobj
    }
    if (strname as AnyObject).isEqual(to: "bottom") {
        tableCellobj = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellmiddle", for: indexPath) as! TableCellMiddle

        tableCellobj.lblMiddle.text = "\(strname)"
        return tableCellobj
    }
```

As you can see the Array `sectionsArray`, is:

```
var sectionsArray: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
sectionsArray.add("top")
sectionsArray.add("bottom")
```

Now the table shows two rows with headers "top" and "bottom"

I have two diffrent data as `NSArray` to be shown in the CollectionView:

```
top = ["1","2","3"]
bottom = ["4","5","6"]
```

the `collectionView` has a tag (identified in Storyboard), so i used the tag to defined the view and show data:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    if collectionView.tag == 2 {

        objCollectionViewCellMiddle = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectioncellmiddle"
        , for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellmiddle

        objCollectionViewCellMiddle.lblMiddle.text = top[indexPath.row] as? String

        return objCollectionViewCellMiddle

    }
```

Now, the TableView shows two CollectionViews, **but it prints same data from `top` array in both CollectionView**

I want:

1st **CollectionView** ---> show the `top` array

2nd **CollectionView** ---> show the `bottom` array

I played around with indexPath.section, but couldn't figure away to make it work as it always prints "0"

Comment: This is because the uitableview is caching the cells as a part of performance  optimisation. Try using different cell identifiers for the UItableViewCells. e.g. cellmiddle1 and cellmiddle2

Comment: @firstinq that means i have to add a new cell from storyboard?

Comment: Your indexPath.section would always be 0 as it has only one section of tableview and one section for each collectionview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think what we need to do here is change around how you're setting things up.  First off, we should change the backing data source to be a value type such as `[String]`:

**MyViewController Class**

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    var sectionsArray: [String] = ["top", "bottom"]
    var topSection: [String] = ["1","2","3"]
    var bottomSection: [String] = ["4","5","6"]

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var topCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomCollectionView: UICollectionView!

}
```

Then, we need to modify the data sources for the table view and collection views:

**Table View Data Source**

```
extension MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let sectionName = sectionsArray[indexPath.section]

        switch sectionName {
        case "top":
            let tableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellmiddle", for: indexPath) as! TableCellMiddle
            tableCell.lblMiddle.text = sectionName
            return tableCell
        case "bottom":
            let tableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellmiddle", for: indexPath) as! TableCellMiddle
            tableCell.lblMiddle.text = sectionName
            return tableCell
        default:
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch section {
        case 0:
            return topSection.count
        case 1:
            return bottomSection.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }
}
```

Here, in the `cellForRow` method you can actually reduce some of the duplicate code as you're doing the same thing regardless of which cell you're at.

**Collection View Data Source**

```
extension MyViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch collectionView {
        case topCollectionView:
            return topSection.count
        case bottomCollectionView:
            return bottomSection.count
        default:
            return 0
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        switch collectionView {
        case topCollectionView:
            let collectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectioncellmiddle", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellmiddle
            collectionCell.lblMiddle.text = topSection[indexPath.row]
            return collectionCell
        case bottomCollectionView:
            let collectionCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectioncellmiddle", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellmiddle
            collectionCell.lblMiddle.text = bottomSection[indexPath.row]
            return collectionCell
        default:
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }
}
```

Here what we're doing is switching on the actual collection view itself that gets passed in as an argument rather than a tag that you set, that way we can easily see which collection view is currently being accessed.  Once we know this we are able to determine which of your backing arrays we need to access and can assign the text accordingly.

You can also reduce some of the duplicate logic in this method if you'd like.

[This](https://gist.github.com/BrandonShega/2806fa138439986e95da24bc79e847b8) is a playground that compiles (I will add functionality later to demonstrate it so it shows up in the timeline).  I think it will help you achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel the problem is in this function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    if collectionView.tag == 2 {

        objCollectionViewCellMiddle = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectioncellmiddle"
        , for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellmiddle

        objCollectionViewCellMiddle.lblMiddle.text = top[indexPath.row] as? String

        return objCollectionViewCellMiddle
    }
}
```

The data assignment shows:

> objCollectionViewCellMiddle.lblMiddle.text = **top[indexPath.row]** as?
>   String

I suggest you change the tableview code by adding the tag code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    let strname = sectionsArray[indexPath.row]
    if (strname as AnyObject).isEqual(to: "top"){
        tableCellobj = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellmiddle", for: indexPath) as! TableCellMiddle

        Add this: tableCellobj.collectionView.tag = 1
        tableCellobj.lblMiddle.text = "\(strname)"
        return tableCellobj
    }
    if (strname as AnyObject).isEqual(to: "bottom") {
        tableCellobj = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellmiddle", for: indexPath) as! TableCellMiddle

        Add this: tableCellobj.collectionView.tag = 2
        tableCellobj.lblMiddle.text = "\(strname)"
        return tableCellobj
    }
```

}

And then:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{

    if collectionView.tag == 1 {

        objCollectionViewCellMiddle = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectioncellmiddle"
        , for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellmiddle

        objCollectionViewCellMiddle.lblMiddle.text = top[indexPath.row] as? String

        return objCollectionViewCellMiddle
    }
    else {

        objCollectionViewCellMiddle = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectioncellmiddle"
        , for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellmiddle

        objCollectionViewCellMiddle.lblMiddle.text = bottom[indexPath.row] as? String

        return objCollectionViewCellMiddle
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think you got the `tag` wrong, as it's defined in the View in storyboard, the only way to manage this is by finding a way to separate both arrays with a statement based on `indexPath.section` or something similar